# Emscripten Clang produce ELF 64-bit executabel and wasm binary cross compiler targets

Tags: clang++, webassembly, emscripten

I have a prepared a minimal Cmake project containing one cpp file which represent the main and one cpp file which represent the shared library, that prints basically hello world. 
https://github.com/courteous/wasmELF.git

The target is to compile this miniaml code with emscripten/clang only and produce

1) one WebAssembly (wasm) binary module version 0x1 (MVP)

2) one ELF 64-bit LSB

without clearing the cmake build directory and rebuilding it again.

Currently i can successfully produce them bought by running the commands

```
emconfigure cmake ../ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=WASM
make
```

and

```
cmake ../ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Linux
make
```

However the problem is that in order to do that i need to compile the first one with Clang the to remove the build  and then to do a second compilation with GCC. I would like Emscripten/Clang to produce them bought instead.  I do not want to delete the build directory since the compilation times is taking too long. (Well not in this Project but imagine if the project was much larger)

What i see is that emscripten/clang  selects always a target "wasm32-unknown-emscripten"

```
clang++ -target wasm32-unknown-emscripten
```

and if i understand that correctly the target should change

I do see that the project is producing LLVM IR bitcode since i have send the flag "flto"

i.e.

```
file TestSharedClass.cpp.o
TestSharedClass.cpp.o: LLVM IR bitcode
```

and in the CMakeLists.txt

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-flto")
```

x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu is a supported target by emscripten/Clang

```
~/Projects/emscripten/emsdk/upstream/bin$ ./llc --version
LLVM (http://llvm.org/):
  LLVM version 11.0.0git
  Optimized build with assertions.
  Default target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  Host CPU: haswell

  Registered Targets:
    wasm32 - WebAssembly 32-bit
    wasm64 - WebAssembly 64-bit
    x86    - 32-bit X86: Pentium-Pro and above
    x86-64 - 64-bit X86: EM64T and AMD64
```

In cmake i do have

```
SET(TARGET x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
```

however when i run

```
emconfigure cmake ../ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Linux
make
```

i get  mainTestFile.js and  mainTestFile.wasm  instead of ELF 64-bitcode.

what i am doing wrong here. How to tell clang to product once ELF and once wasm from the same code run  without having to clear the build directory. This should be possible since clang is producing LLVM IR bitcode. Or do i understand that wrong?

https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/10361

Answer (score 0):

OK that seems to not be possible i.e. the reply from the dev on github states that emcc or emmake can not be used with another target other then wasm32-unknown-emscripten.